# Feign client execution failure: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-feign, netflix-ribbon

I have problem in inter-service communication load balancing.

I am using spring (1.4.2), spring cloud with netflixOSS.

I have two services shoppingcart-service and user-service.

Here is ShoppingCartController from shopppingcart-service app:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("shoppingCarts")
public class ShoppingCartController extends AbstractRESTController<ShoppingCart, String>{

private ShoppingCartService shoppingCartSrevice;

@Autowired
public ShoppingCartController(ShoppingCartService service) {
    super(service);
    this.shoppingCartSrevice = service;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "{userId}/createShoppingCart", method = RequestMethod.POST)
ShoppingCart createShoppingCart(
        @RequestBody List<CartItem> items,
        @PathVariable(name = "userId") String userId
        ){

    Boolean userOK = shoppingCartSrevice.checkUser(userId);

    if(userOK != null)
        if(userOK)
            return shoppingCartSrevice.createShoppingCart(items, userId);

    return null;
}

@FeignClient("user-service")//the server.port property name, for the "server" service
public interface UserServiceClient {
    @RequestMapping(value = "users/checkUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)// the endpoint which will be balanced over
    Boolean checkUser(
            @RequestParam(name = "userId") String userId);// the method specification must be the same as for users/hello
}
```

}

> "checkUser"

methosd is from ShoppingCartService class:

```
@Service
public class ShoppingCartService extends AbstractCRUDService<ShoppingCart, String>{

private ShoppingCartRepository shoppingCartRepository;
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Autowired
private UserServiceClient userServiceClient;// feign client

@Autowired
public ShoppingCartService(ShoppingCartRepository repo, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
    super(repo);
    this.shoppingCartRepository = repo;
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;

}

/**
 * Method checks if the given user is registered and active
 * We use Ribbon and Feign to get data from user-service, load-balancing 
 * @param userId
 * @return
 */
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod="fallbackCheckUser")
public Boolean checkUser(String userId) {

    /*USING LOAD-BALANCING*/
     Boolean resp = userServiceClient.checkUser(userId);//HERE I GET THE EXCEPTION
     return resp;
}

public Boolean fallbackCheckUser(String userId){
    return true;
}
```

When I try to execute checkUser(userId) @HystricsCommand method I get: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.

Please HELP.

UPDATE 1:

shoppingcart-service pom.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>rs.uns.acs.ftn</groupId>
    <artifactId>ShoppingCartService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>ShoppingCartService</name>
    <description>Shopping Cart Service</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-ribbon</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jglue.fluent-json</groupId>
            <artifactId>fluent-json</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Camden.SR2</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Please add more of the exception. That single line is useless.

Comment: The stack trace is empty on exception object, also I don't get any output on console. I have also running 3 more services alongside Eureka and Zuul. I will put pom.xml for shoppingcart-service, please see update.

Comment: I don't know how to help, unless you can provide a sample. Camden.SR6 is the latest in the Camden release train.

Comment: com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: UserServiceClient#checkUser(String) failed while executing. Does this make any ideas? This is only I can get.

Comment: I think I know what I did. I had two services with Feign client specifications that was the same aka:  @FeignClient("user-service"). @spencergibb can you tell why?

Comment: Final conclusions: 1. I was using STS IDE for development and starting apps. For some reason this native starting does not works properly. If I start service like right-click->run as Java Application, than the first request fails on fallback method, and every new request passes without problems. When I make .jar files using mvn build, the same behavior: firs request triggers fallback method, every other passes. If someone can explain this, please comment.

Comment: I have no idea.

Answer (score -1):

`Spring Cloud`, `Feign`, `Ribbon` aside these "`REST`" endpoints don't seem to follow recommended practices.

`POST` to check if a user exists doesn't look right, `POST` are normally used to create a resource such as a user or product.

`POST` to /..../{userId}/createShoppingCart doesn't look right either. nouns are recommended in `REST` API Design, /users, /products, /users/{id} and HTTP verbs (POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, GET, ....) represent operations on those "nouns": POST /users means create a user, PUT /products/{id} means update product whose id is {id}. Verbs are usually not recommended as part of the URL.

And as @spencergibb mentioned, without the config files (application.yml or properties), the source code and meaningful stacktrace it would be very difficult to troubleshot this issue.

One possible issue might be your `pom` file missing the `<start-class>` element inside `<properties>`.

Comment: The HTTP API specification is different from user case to use case. But this is noting to do with the issue that I have right now.